# Dúvidas com versionamento Git Hub

Tags: git

Olá, eu estou com uma dificuldade extrema que não achei resposta nem relação no oráculo onisciente.

Meu problema: Eu estou escrevendo algumas linhas, testo o que eu fiz, dou commit, dou pull e push, resolvo conflitos e dou merge. O problema é que quando eu faço isso, meu repositório local fica "up date" e o repositório do deploy tbm fica "up date"( que é o esperado), entretanto as minhas modificações não aparecem na mina aplicação.

O git não apresenta nenhum erro, com o git status diz que não há nenhuma modificação a commitar, com o git pull diz que o local já esta atualizado e com o push diz que o remoto já está atualizado, mas mesmo assim os códigos das aplicações local e online não são os mesmo.

Alguém sabe oq é e como corrigir???

OBS: Eu uso o Atom para escrever e controlar os commits, dar pull, push e merge.

Comment: As operações que estás fazendo, são todas no branch correto? (não sei se o sistema de build que usas constroi a aplicação com o código que está no master ou em algum outro branch)

Comment: Outra coisa que pode estar fazendo é merge incorreto, que acaba sobrescrevendo tuas alterações com código antigo...

Comment: Eu já olhei as branchs, eu dou commit na minha branch de develop dou push e depois faço o merge pra master, dai eu dou pull do espelho do servidor do serviço.
Eu fazia assim até agora e tudo funcionava normal, mas de uns dias pra cá ficou assim.
Vlw a resposta Leonardo, mas acho que não é isso.